# 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' does not contain a definition for 'get_Default'

Tags: c#, excel

when i try to export datagrid value to excel it show's error on following line.

```
range = (Range)worksheet.Cells.get_Default(num2 + 10, num);
```

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' does not contain a definition
>   for 'get_Default' and no extension method 'get_Default' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

some more code

```
for (int k = inFirstCol; k < dgv.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    range = (Range)worksheet.Cells.get_Default(num2 + 10, num);

    if (dgv[k, j].Style.Font != null)
    {
        if (dgv[k, j].Style.Font.Bold)
        {
            range.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because such a method does not exist on the Range interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_methods.aspx

Comment: @mehow could u help any alternative to 3rd line of the code

Comment: @Maili what are you trying to do by using so called `get_Default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using C# version 4, the synthetic get_Default() method is no longer generated.  The WorkSheet interface now has a real indexer, you use it like you do in the rest of your code.  Fix:

```
  range = (Range)worksheet.Cells[num2 + 10, num];
```

I'll briefly describe what get_Default() was all about.  COM Automation has a more flexible notion of properties, it supports *indexed* properties.  Or in other words, properties that can take extra arguments.  It also permits declaring a property as the default property of an interface.

The C# language has historically been *very* strict about this.  It does support a default property but it has a fixed name: *this*.  The indexer of a class.  It is renamed to `Item` when the program is built.  And it *must* have a single argument.  This did not play that well with COM interop where the default property can have any name and an arbitrary number of arguments.  The Range interface has that problem, it has a default property named `Value` that takes two arguments.  They are optional as well, something else that was not supported in C#.  So the type library importer worked around that restriction by synthesizing a fake member named "Default".  And generated the get_Default() and set_Default() methods to support two arguments.

C# version 4 greatly improved this, it now supports indexed properties as well.  But only in the specific case of COM interop.  If you look at the Range interface with Object Explorer you now see:

```
  dynamic this[[object RowIndex = System.Type.Missing], 
               [object ColumnIndex = System.Type.Missing]] 
  { set; get; }
```

And get_Default() is no longer present.